# How do I store information about a front-end button on the Django server?

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

Basically I want to store a buttons service server-side that way it can persist through browser closes and page refresh.

**Here's what the user is trying to do**

1. The user searches in a search bar for a list of products.
2. When the results show up, they are shown a button that triggers an action for each individual product. They are also shown a master button that can trigger the same action for each product that is listed.
3. Upon clicking the button, I want to disable it for 30 seconds and have this persist through page refreshes and browser close.

**What I've done**

Currently I have this implemented using AJAX calls on the client side, but if the page refreshes it resets the button and they can click it again. So I looked into using javascript's localStorage function, but in my situation it would be better just to store this on the server.

**What I think needs to happen**

1. Create a model in my Django app for a button. Its attributes would be its status and maybe some meta data (last clicked, etc).
2. Whenever the client requests a list of products, the views will send the list of products and it will be able to query the database for the respective button's status and implement a disabled attribute directly into the template.
3. If the button is available to be pressed then the client side will make an AJAX POST call to the server and the server will check the buttons status. If it's available it will perform the action, update the buttons status to disabled for 30 seconds, and send this info back to the client in order to reflect it in the DOM.

**A couple questions**

1. Is it just a matter of creating a model for the buttons and then querying the database like normal?
2. How do I have Django update the database after 30 seconds to make a button's status go from disabled back to enabled?
3. When the user presses the button it's going to make it disabled, but it will only be making it disabled in the database. What is the proper way to actually disable the button without a page refresh on the client side? Do I just disable the button in javascript for 30 seconds, and then if they try to refresh the page then the views will see the request for the list of products and it will check the database for each button's status and it will serve the button correctly?

Thank you very much for the help!!

Comment: what are your use case for disabling the button for 30 seconds? Can the same be achieved by a write lock in the db?

Comment: @SaurabhAriyan I'm not sure I fully understand your question but I'll try to answer it.  I don't think the same can be achieved by a write lock in the db. I don't even want the user to be able to click the button if it was just clicked within the past 30 seconds. I feel like in your suggestion they would still be able to click it but it just wouldn't do anything on the server side. I feel like having it disabled gives good user feedback that they can't click it again until the time is up.

Comment: Will the button disable feature will be independent for each user? If user A has disabled the button, will it disable the button for user B as well? Also how many such buttons are there in the app? Is it only one particular button or it grows based on the number of product?

Comment: Ahh I see, sorry about that. Yes if user A disables the button it should be disabled for all other users. Right now I have implemented a database storage solution that is a WIP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it just a matter of creating a model for the buttons and then
>   querying the database like normal?

Model could be something like `Button (_id, last_clicked as timestamp, user_id)`
While querying you could simply sort by `timestamp` and `LIMIT` 1 to get the last click. By not overwriting the original value it would ensure a bit faster write.

If you don't want the buttons to behave similarly for each user you will have to create a mapping of the button with the user who clicked it. Even if your current requirements don't need them, create an extensible solution where mapping the user with this table is quite easy.

> How do I have Django update the database after 30 seconds to make a
>   button's status go from disabled back to enabled?

I avoid changing the database without a client request mapped to the change. This ensures the concurrency and access controls. And also has higher predictability for the current state of data. Following that, I would suggest not to update the db after the time delta(30 sec).

Instead of that you could simply compare the `last_clicked` timestamp and calculate the delta either server side before sending the response or in client side.

This decision could be important, consider a scenario when the client has a different time on his system than the server time.

> When the user presses the button it's going to make it disabled, but
>   it will only be making it disabled in the database. What is the proper
>   way to actually disable the button without a page refresh on the
>   client side? Do I just disable the button in javascript for 30
>   seconds, and then if they try to refresh the page then the views will
>   see the request for the list of products and it will check the
>   database for each button's status and it will serve the button
>   correctly?

You'd need to do a `POST` request to communicate the button press timestamp with the db. You'd also need to ensure that the `POST` request is successful as an unsuccessful request would not persist the data in case of browser closure. 
After doing the above two you could disable the button only from the client side without trying the get the button `last_clicked` timestamp.

Comment: Awesome this is extremely helpful. I have a quick question: what would be the best way to get the client's timezone in the `views.py` file? In `views.py` I want to handle all the logic of comparing the client's time to the `last_clicked` timestamp and the just send to the client the amount of time until the button can be activated again. In my `settings.py` I have a timezone configured, but if I were to get `datetime.datetime.now()` in python, how would I make that get the client's time in their respective timezone?

Comment: Depending upon your use case, you should not send the timestamp back to the client to calculate the time to activate the button. Consider two users in the same timezone, User A is 2 mins behind User B. User A disables the button, if you send the last clicked time stamp directly to User B he would be able to click the button without waiting, as he's already 2 mins ahead. 

Either you could use libraries which extract the timezone for the user based on the IP address or you could simply save the user timezone in the user model. And send the delta to the client.